# Testing oAuth / facebook authentication with WebTestCase in Symfony2

Tags: facebook, testing, oauth, symfony, webtest

I'm trying to get a FacebookLoginTest running.
Problem is: the Symfony2 client does not send real HTTP requests, so it does not work on URLs of other services (like facebook).

I know I could work with cUrl,... but I see so many obstacles there: session, javascript, redirects.

Any ideas how we could get this running? Anyone got a automatic oAuth test running?

Comment: You should have a look to Facebook test users. They have a unique loginURL designed for automated testing. But those will only feet client-side testing for the same reasons you pointed out.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Comment: Facebook test users is a good idea. It's the user you'll log. But this is not how you can redirect to the login url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be Goutte https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte which is a wrapper around the Sf2 components you're using combined with an HTTP client. Good luck!

Comment: Goutte is not working for me. Seems like there is a lot of JS stuff going on in the facebook login form...

Answer (score 0):

curl should work just fine for this, and while it doesn't support javascript,  you won't need js support for what you're trying to accomplish.